# jQuery capitilize first letter each word

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have been using jQuery address plugin and it passes an event.value which might result in `/messages/inbox/`. I want to be able to turn that into `Messages Inbox`.

I am not sure which regex to use and how to do this.  Currently I have this, but this is just way too messy for me.

```
var href = event.value != '/' ? event.value : '/wall/';
var title1 = href.replace('/', "");
var title2 = title1.replace('/', " ");
var myTitle = title2.replace('/', "");
$.address.title("My-Site | " + myTitle);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little tidier; lop off the start and end characters, then replace the middle, then run a regex replace to swap the characters for uppercase versions:

```
var href = event.value != '/' ? event.value : '/wall/',
    title = href.slice(1, -1).replace("/", " "),
    myTitle = title.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function ($0) {
        return $0.toUpperCase();
    });

$.address.title("My-Site | " + myTitle);
```

Methods used:

- [*replace()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [*toUpperCase()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Comment: Nice. Beware of the limitations of JavaScript regular expressions: only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _ are considered word characters, so words starting in other characters such as accented letters will not be capitalized correctly.