# Capitalize input text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea, capitalize

In a form, I have two buttons to transform text to uppercase and lowercase. I am using this function to transform input text to upper case:

```
document.xyz.textinput.value=document.xyz.textinput.value.toUpperCase()
```

Now, I want to add a new button to capitalize each word. Is it possible to achieve this with the following code?

```
document.xyz.textinput.value=document.xyz.textinput.value.capitalize()
```

Thanks

Comment: No, because that function (capitalize) doesnt exist.

Comment: _"Is it possible to achieve this with the following code"_, what happens if you try it?

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/899

Comment: Posted wrong duplicate link before, this is the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777172/jquery-capitilize-first-letter-each-word

Comment: By "each word" do you mean one word at a time, or all of them? And by "word" do you mean a group of characters sepatated by a word break character or space? *String.prototype.toUpperCase()* only transforms characters a-z to A-Z respectively, which capitalises only alphabetic characters (i.e. all words in the string).

Comment: @RobG A group of alphabets separated with a space.

Comment: @Leo, well, then your question could have simply been answered with a "no". My point is, you should have posted the fact that "it didn't work" and should ideally have included the exact error message you saw on your screen.

Comment: @BartKiers Sorry about that. It's my first time here. Will remember your point and be clear the next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
document.xyz.textinput.value = document.xyz.textinput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + document.xyz.textinput.slice(1);
```

If you want a capitalize functions, [See here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/text/case-capitalize.html).

Comment: The link did what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Hari Krishnan's answer is a bit more formal JS (extending the prototype) instead of strictly procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has some text-transform properties too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform

If that isnt an option, you can simply split your string by each whitespace and capitalize that word.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function (strSentence) {
        return strSentence.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, convertToUpper);

        function convertToUpper() {
            return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
        }
}
```

Use this:

```
"hello world".capitalize();  // "Hello World"
```

Comment: But the poster wanted to capitalize each word

Comment: I didn't read it properly at first and later **updated** the code. Please check now

Comment: This might be more clearly named as titlecase or titleize instead of capitalize since it upcases every word.